# OCaml turning a string to an array of chars without the blank spaces

Tags: arrays, string, ocaml

I am doing an OCaml assignment, and I am stuck in a part where I need to convert a string to an array of chars.

The requirement is that the result array should have no blank spaces. For example,

Given input:

```
let s = "This is a string test";;
```

the output should be

```
 [|'t'; 'h'; 'i'; 's'; 'i'; 's'; 'a';'s';'t';'r';'i';'n';'g';'t';'t';'e';'s';'t';|];
```

for this problem im using the following instruction

```
let test = Array.init (String.length y) (fun t -> y.[t]);;
```

but the value of `test` has blank spaces `' '` in it.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the array most likely won't be the same size as the string, so using `Array.init` isn't a good solution. So let's look at what you want to do:

- You are mapping each character into an entry of an array.
- The mapping is conditional since you don't want spaces included.
- You don't know the final size of the array, so you need to dynamically create it.

Here's one approach:

- `Array.concat` concatenates a list of arrays into a single array.
- Convert the string into a list of tiny arrays -- each element of the list is an array of a single character or an empty array, if it was a space.

Since this is an assignment, I'll let you write the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other ways to do this. Since this is an asignment I won't give you code though, just the idea.

1. Convert the string into a char list, filter out all the ' ' (this can be done in one loop or two). Then convert the list to array.
2. count the number of not spaces in the string, create a suitable array, loop over the string copying the chars into the array (skipping the spaces)